# zsh return a series of "unknown error" to all the plugins when prompting zplug status

Tags: debian, zsh

I am problems with my zsh plugins:

```
zplug status
[zplug] Start to get remote status 9 plugins in parallel

 ⠦  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completions
 ⠧  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completionslighting
 ⠇  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completionslighting
 ⠏  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completionslighting
 ⠋  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completionslightingearch
 ⠹  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completionslightingearch
 ⠹  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlightingon: operator expected at `0'
 ⠦  Fetching...           zsh-users/zsh-completionsionsng-search
 ✘  Unknown error         zsh-users/zsh-completionslightingearch
 ✘  Unknown error         zsh-users/zsh-completionslightingearch
 ✘  Unknown error         zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
 ✘  Unknown error         zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestionsng-searchperator expected at `0'
 ✘  Unknown error         junegunn/fzfh-history-substring-search
 ✘  Unknown error         zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search
 ✘  Unknown error         plugins/command-not-found
 ✘  Unknown error         plugins/sudorussell math expression: operator expected at `0'
 ✘  Unknown error         plugins/gityrussell
 ✘  Unknown error         themes/robbyrussell

[zplug] Elapsed time: 3.2254 sec.tate:21: bad math expression: operator expected at `0'
 ==> All packages are up-to-date!
```

...and indeed they do not work as expected.

My `.zshrc` file is the same as suggested in the [Debian zsh page](https://wiki.debian.org/Zsh), with the following lines at the bottom:

```
# Loading the custom config files
for config_file in ~/.sh/*.sh; do
  source "$config_file"
done
```